# Where does scanf leave the file pointer?

Tags: c, scanf

So I have something like this:

```
while (scanf("somepattern",arg1,arg2)==2) {
   if(arg1==0) break;
   <code here>
}

if(scanf("someotherpattern")==1) {
   <code here>
}
```

My question is: after matching all patterns equal to 2, where is the `scanf` function pointing to in the file? Did it consume the "0" in the `if` or not?

Comment: Do you mean `fscanf()`? since `scanf()` is fixed to `stdin`

Comment: @Mike: Why does that matter? `stdin` has a current position like any other stream.

Comment: @Keith: it matters because I'm trying to ascertain what, exactly, is being asked here. Since the code clearly isn't real, and the question doesn't make sense to me I'm hoping I can either prompt a correction to the question or get a clarification leading to understanding what is being asked.

Comment: @Mike: The answer is going to be the same for `stdin` as for any other stream. (If you're concerned about the behavior on interactive and/or seekable streams, that's an orthogonal issue; `stdin`, or an other stream, can be interactive or not.)

Answer (score 2):

The character that would cause a *matching failure* remains unread. The standard says so several times in the description of `fscanf`.

Comment: Nicely put.  Would also like to add that `scanf()` also stops on I/O error or EOF.